# Reduce Fontsize of Tabspec Indicator

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Please is there a way to reduce the font size of Tab Indicator? Here is my code and the screen shot of the App in an emulator. I also tried to use an image instead of the text,but the image doesn't show up in the emulator. I cant add the image,said i need at least 10 reputation to do so.

```
public class Landing extends TabActivity
```

{

```
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.landing);

                // create the TabHost that will contain the Tabs
                TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);


                TabSpec predict = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
                TabSpec predictions = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");
                TabSpec leaders = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third tab");
                TabSpec blog = tabHost.newTabSpec("fourth tab");



                predict.setIndicator("HOME ");
                predict.setContent(new Intent(this,Home.class));

                predictions.setIndicator("Predictions");
                predictions.setContent(new Intent(this,Mypredictions.class));

                leaders.setIndicator("Leaders");
               leaders.setContent(new Intent(this,Leaders.class));

               blog.setIndicator("Blog");
               blog.setContent(new Intent(this,Blog.class));


                tabHost.addTab(predict);
                tabHost.addTab(predictions);
                tabHost.addTab(leaders);
                tabHost.addTab(blog);

        }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is.
First, create a layout xml with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tab_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="@color/granite" />
```

here you can set the text size.

Then in java inflate this layout and add it as a view for the tab's indicator:

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) View.inflate(context, R.layout.tab_view, null);
tab1.setIndicator(tv1);
```